# Against what resource service check bearer/access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0

When a client send a request to resource service with OAuth access token,
how resource service check the access token?. Does resource server validate access token against some entity ?

Answer (score 0):

When resource server get a request with a OAuth access token, it have two options to validate the access token.

First option is to contact `token introspection endpoint` of the authorization server. This endpoint is a standard endpoint defined by [RFC7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) which is a part of OAuth 2.0 specification. According to that spec. resource server can will send a token introspection request to authorization server. If access token is valid (ex:- Not yet expired) then response will contain a `active=true` state. Please go through RFC7662 to understand how this works.

Second option is to use self contained token. In this approach, authorization server issue JWT based access tokens. Once resource server receive this token, it can go through contents of JWT to identify validity of the access token.

Answer (score 0):

The validation of the token against a specific operation on a specific resource is done using oauth2 [scopes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-23)

The way the resource server performs the validation itself [depends on the implementation](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/the-resource-server/), the simplest way is to use "self contained tokens" e.g. JWT ones so you can get the scopes from the token itself without additional lookup.

If your server exposes resources using traditional http REST semantic, the simplest implementation is to use an http middleware / filter which just check the resource uri and the http verb to determine the validity of the operation